# How to convert some specific columns to float?

Tags: python, list

I am writing a code that takes information from a .data file (it is iris.data), I have this code:

```
lines=file_2.readlines()
list_2=[]
for k in range(len(lines)):
    lines[k]=lines[k][0:len(lines[k])-1]
    list_2.append(lines[k].split(","))
print(list_2)
file_2.close()
```

And the result is like this:

`[['5.1', '3.5', '1.4', '0.2', 'Iris-setosa'], ['4.9', '3.0', '1.4', '0.2', 'Iris-setosa'].....[ +147 lists]]`

My question is, is there a way that the result can be like this:(maybe converting the first 4 columns of each list to float(?))

`[[5.1, 3.5, 1.4, 0.2, 'Iris-setosa'][4.9, 3.0, 1.4, 0.2, 'Iris-setosa']....]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could define a function like the following:

```
def convert(item):
    try:
        return float(item)
    except ValueError:
        return item
```

and then call it inside a list comprehension, which you can append to your `list_2` list.

By the way, I suspect that you do this -> `lines[k] = lines[k][0:len(lines[k]) - 1]` to remove the trailing new-line character (`\n`) from each line of the file that you are reading. A cleaner way to do it would be as follows:

```
lines = file_2.read().splitlines()
file_2.close()

list_2 = []
for line in lines:
    list_2.append([convert(item) for item in line.split(",")])
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest saving your file in a .csv format and loading it as a panda dataframe. Most machine learning libraries work well with the panda dataframe, and you should probably use it.

You can also download the .csv file here: https://www.kaggle.com/uciml/iris

But for your problem:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(list_2, columns = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'Species'])
df = df.astype({"a": float, "b": float, "c": float, "d": float})
list_2 = list(df.values)
```

Answer (score 0):

A basic solution would be to iterate through the list to convert the values to `float` such as following,

```
l1=[['5.1', '3.5', '1.4', '0.2', 'Iris-setosa'], ['4.9', '3.0', '1.4', '0.2', 'Iris-setosa']]
for i in range(len(l1)):
    for j in range(4):
        try:
            l1[i][j]=float(l1[i][j])
        except:
            print("not a float value")

print(l1)
```

output:

```
[[5.1, 3.5, 1.4, 0.2, 'Iris-setosa'], [4.9, 3.0, 1.4, 0.2, 'Iris-setosa']]
```

but the problem with this solution is, it will require more time as the length of list increases.The solution will work effectively for a smaller list